# Why does $A$ have an inverse if $AX=B$, where X is a column matrix, $X=(x_1,...,x_n)^t$, has a unique solution for every $n\times1$-matrix $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

My textbook in linear algebra states that the following statements are equivalent:

1. A has an inverse
2. A can be reduced to the indentity matrix, by applying row operations.
3. The equation system $AX=B$, where X is a column matrix, $X=(x_1,...,x_n)^t$, has a unique solution for every $n\times1$-matrix $B$.

I'm having a hard time visualizing/rationalizing 3) to myself. Why would this be the case and why would 3) be sufficient to prove that a matrix has an inverse?

Comment: It means you have a 1 to 1 correspondence between the n-tuples in the form of $X$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

For any vector $X$, $AX$ denotes a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Now if for every vector $B$, $AX=B$ has a solution, this means that every vector $B$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. This implies that the column of $A$ form a basis for the vector space, and hence implying that they are linearly independent. Hence $A$ is full rank and will have an inverse.

*Implication of uniqueness of solutions*: Suppose there is a $B$ for which there are more than one solutions: say $AX_1=B=AX_2$ where $X_1\ne X_2$. Then we have $A(X_1-X_2)=0$ and $X_1-X_2\ne0$. Thus we have a non-trivial linear combination of the columns of $A$ that yields the $0$ vector. Hence the columns of $A$ are not linearly independent. Then the matrix will not have full rank, and hence will not be invertble

Comment: I don't know, how  would the situation look where $AX=B$ did "not" have unique solutions for every different $B$?

Comment: Also, exactly what does "unique solution" mean in this case? Are we using the term colloquially (so that every $X$ has a different value depending on $B$) or are we saying that the coefficient matrix of the linear transformation can be reduced to the identity matrix, and that all elements in $B$  thus can be specified uniquely?

Comment: I have edited the answer to incorporate your questions

Comment: Okay, you're using the fact that matrices display the distributive property(ies) I think to illustrate that in that case, the linear transformations would yield the same result despite being different. But what's that part about non-trivial linear combinations yielding the 0 vector, and why would that imply non-independence of the columns?

Apologies for being dense ^^

Comment: Vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ are called linearly dependent if there exists scalars $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n$, not all zero, such that  $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$. Now let the columns of $A$, be $A_1,A_2,\cdots, A_n$. and Let $X_1-X_2$ be the column vector $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)^t$. Then $A(X_1-X_2)=x_1A_1+x_2A_2+\cdots x_nA_n=0$. Now not all of the $x_i$'s are zero, because $X_1\ne X_2$. Hence we have that $A_1,A_2,\cdots, A_n$ are linearly dependent.